# Run keras model (.h5) on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I trained a model in keras on a Linux platform and saved the model with a `model.save_weights("demandFinal.h5")`

And then I was hoping to take my complete saved model to IPython on my Windows 10 laptop running Anaconda 3.7 and use it with:

```
from keras.models import load_model

# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("demandFinal.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

But I am running into some issues.. First I forgot Keras wasn't installed so I did a `!pip install keras` no problems. Then `!pip install Tensorflow` whether that was needed or not..

Now I have a numpy error:

`ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import`

After some research online, I did a `pip install -U numpy` which installed that package... But I still have the same issue.. When I run the `load_model` in IPython anaconda 3.7, this will cause the kernel to crash/restart. Full traceback:

```
C:\Users\bbartling\Desktop\EC

Using TensorFlow backend.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Hopefully I didn't screw up my anaconda installation... But would anyone have any tips to try? Sorry not a lot of wisdom here... But maybe there is a better way to save the model as json or yml file to the process I was hoping run the model on a Windows machine after the training...

Do utilize a deep learning model on a Windows machine do I need the deep learning libraries installed? I was hoping to not have to install Tensorflow

***EDIT***

See this follow up [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050339/keras-prediction-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-predict?noredirect=1#comment96850733_55050339) as final solution

Answer (score 0):

idk actualy what is anaconda but anaconda users's path where python files stored not looks healty and almost all anaconda users's path looks different

but this error causes numpy version probably youre using numpy 1.15 wich doesnot have `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`. upgrading numpy to 1.16 hopfuly solve error

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.16.1
```

after installation run `python -c "import numpy.core._multiarray_umath"` if you get error you have a problem with numpy installation.

edit) package installation for anaconda:

- for current environment:

  conda install numpy=1.16.1
- for spesific environment:

  conda install numpy=1.16.1 -n python37_environment

Comment: Still same issue.. Got any ideas?

Comment: @HenryHub can you execute python -c "import numpy.core._multiarray_umath" what output you get. if you get error your numpy 1.16.1 installation is incorrect.

Comment: On my Windows 10 laptop I did the `pip install --upgrade numpy==1.16.1` in both 3.6 python & anaconda 3.7
. In IDLE 3.6, the shell command prompt this appears to import without any problems `>>> import numpy.core._multiarray_umath` but in IPython 3.7, Im getting a `
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8d3c7ed14171> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy.core._multiarray_umath

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

Comment: Is it easiest to ditch the IPython anaconda route and just use ordinary (my limited understanding of software) Python (IDLE)? When I run the code in 3.6 IDLE, I am getting a `ValueError: Cannot create group in read only mode.` But researching online there is a Keras git issue (link below) for this and I think the fix from reading this is to ` solved it by manually defining the architecture and then loading the weights.` Any tips on how to move forward in a direction would be greatly appreciated. How would I manually define the architecture on this route?

Comment: https://github.com/michalfaber/keras_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation/issues/100

Comment: This link is a git gist of my code in Keras, its a simple regression application. https://gist.github.com/bbartling/472d27bf523b46e6321a362b08b394be

Comment: are you sure youre installing package right? pls look at that https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html